# Regex match parts of time individually in format hh:mm:ss

Tags: sql-server, regex, vb.net

For example, an item has a duration of 00:45:00; I need to have some code, be it regex or VB, to create variables for hour (here 00), mins (here 45) and seconds (00).

My idea is store the duration of an event in a database in seconds - the events only have a duration and don't have start dates or times as the duration has to be used multiple times with different start times. I'm using SQL Server and can't find a data type that supports a duration in this way, so I'm having to convert to seconds (unless there is another way to do it properly).

Thanks.

Comment: Working with time spans and durations in sql server  http://www.sqlteam.com/article/working-with-time-spans-and-durations-in-sql-server

Comment: SQL Server **2008** and newer have a [`TIME` datatype](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the time datatype introduced in 2008 you can do this easily with DATEDIFF.

```
declare @time time = '00:45:00'

select DATEDIFF(second, 0, @time)
```